# Minted: no margin outside of frame when using background color

Tags: minted, syntax-highlighting, frame

I am using minted with a background color and a frame (see MWE below) for displaying code with syntax highlighting in my document. How can I remove the space (see red arrows in image below) outside of the frame so that the frame and edge of the background overlap? There should not be any gray outside of the frame.

[image]

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}
[
frame=single,
framesep=2mm,
bgcolor=LightGray
]
{cpp}
std::vector<int> test;

example_function();
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put     `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}` before `\begin{minted}`

[image: d]

Comment: Thanks, that solved it perfectly and without any bigger effort.